# why a[n] is accepted in c during runtime?

Tags: c, arrays, declare

why can we do this in c?

```
int n;
scanf("%d",&n);
int a[n];
```

I thought array is located memory during load time but seems like the above example works during runtime.
Do I misunderstand any thing? can you guys help?

Thanks,

Comment: It is also provided as an extension by g++ although VLA is not a part of C++(but will be a part of C++0x).

Comment: The C++ extension does not include support for references to a variable length array type; neither may a function parameter be a reference to a variable length array type.(IBM C++)

Comment: No, it won't be part of C++0x.

Comment: @Debanjan

Read my comment. I said it is just provided as an extension. It is not a part of C++.

Comment: @Prasoon: some of the new C99 features will likely be included in the next C++0x, but I don't think VLAs should be included.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`I thought array is *al*located memory during load time but seems like the above example works during run-time.`

Yes, ordinary arrays like `<datatype> <Array_Name>  [<size>]` is allocated memory during load time it is there in C89 and also existed in C99.

But in the code snippet `int a[n];` is a Variable Length Array or VLA for short.VLA's in C99 are defined just like any other array, except that the length doesn’t need to be a compile-time constant.

A decent article on the need of VLAs can be found here :http://www.ddj.com/cpp/184401444 :)

Answer (score 9):

I am no expert in C, but this could be a [variable-length array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) as added by [C99](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99) and [supported by GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html), for example. GCC allocates the memory for such array on stack, so that it gets automatically freed when you return from the function.

Comment: This is VLA(C99 feature), why are you not sure?

Comment: I said I was not expert in C, because although I know there is such thing as VLAs, I have never used them and I wasn’t 100% sure this is what poster was talking about.

Answer (score 7):

[Variable-length arrays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) are not found in C89, but are a new feature in C99.

Answer (score 0):

Given how your code is written (specifically, that you have a statement), this must be code within a function.

While I'm not sure if this is strictly required in the spec, within a function, all auto (i.e. function level, not static) arrays are put on the stack.  So regardless of whether you have a regular or VL array, the memory is allocated at runtime.

The memory for non-auto arrays is not handled at runtime so do no support VLA.  If you try to compile the following code:

```
extern int size;
char buff1[size];

void doit(int x)
{
    static int buff2[x];
    int buff3[x];
}
```

On the compiler I tested this on (gcc 4.2.1), I got following errors:

```
moo.c:2: error: variably modified ‘buff1’ at file scope
moo.c: In function ‘doit’:
moo.c:6: error: storage size of ‘buff2’ isn’t constant
```