# Declaring local arrays using non-const variables to set the length, and it works?

Tags: c++, arrays, constants, declaration

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [why a[n] is accepted in c during runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1864840/why-an-is-accepted-in-c-during-runtime)
>   [Declaring the array size with a non-constant variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2863347/declaring-the-array-size-with-a-non-constant-variable)

I just wrote some code to test some other code and I needed an array as input data. As the size of the input data may differ, I declared the variable as follows:

```
float input[num_pixels_row][num_pixels_col][3];
```

where `num_pixels_row` and `num_pixels_col` are non-const variables which are set using input from the command line. I ran the code and it worked.

Then after a little while I noticed what I had just done and thought "Hey, wait a minute! This shouldn't work!!" But the strange thing is that it does. Since `input` is declared inside a function it should be allocated on the stack, but how can the compiler determine the stack frame if the size of the array isn't known?

I asked two colleagues and they were just as puzzled. By the way, I compiled the code using g++ 4.6.1

Comment: Try compiling it with something other than g++ and see if that works.

Comment: Please check here [1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2863347/declaring-the-array-size-with-a-non-constant-variable

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/737240/c-c-array-size-at-run-time-w-o-dynamic-allocation-is-allowed

Comment: Could also check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1864840/why-an-is-accepted-in-c-during-runtime

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Variable length arrays are a part of the C99 specification, which gcc also allows in C++ programs.

I don't think this has been added to C++11 though, unfortunately. Though I'd suspect that since many C++ compilers also strive for C compliance that they'll end up supporting this as well.

Comment: Well, VLAs have been made optional in C1x, so it's possible that some C++ compilers (and even C compilers) will ignore VLAs.

Comment: Which section states they are optional? I couldn't find it when I looked.

Comment: I have last April's draft. It's in §6.10.8.3. `#define __STDC_NO_VLA__ 1` is a conformant "implementation" of VLAs :) At the end of §6.7.6.2p4 it's explicitly stated implementations need not support them.

Comment: I think we need somebody with a final copy, since my draft from Feb 2011 doesn't contain reference to that define or VLAs.

Comment: This draft from November http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1539.pdf is the draft that is going for CD ballot. It may take a while until there is a final copy :)

Answer (score 4):

That's a gcc-specific compiler extension which makes your code sub-standard and nonportable. For example, this won't compile in Visual C++.